# Proactive messaging throwing Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'

Tags: .net-core, botframework, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-bot-service

I'm trying to store the conversation reference for chats between user and our bot, and use that chat reference to send other messages later.
I'm saving the following entities in our DB:

```
string UserAadObjectId { get; set; }
string UserId { get; set; }
string UserName { get; set; }
string ConversationId { get; set; }
string ConversationType { get; set; }
string ConversationTenantId { get; set; }
string ChannelId { get; set; }
string ActivityId { get; set; }
string BotId { get; set; }
string BotName { get; set; }
string ConversationReference { get; set; }
string ServiceUrl { get; set; }
```

After getting these entities for a specific user, I'm creating a conversation reference as following:(Where **chatReference** is the sql database for the entities above)

```
var user = new ChannelAccount(chatReference.UserId, chatReference.UserName, null, chatReference.UserAadObjectId);
var bot = new ChannelAccount(chatReference.BotId, chatReference.BotName);
var conversationAccount = new ConversationAccount(conversationType: chatReference.ConversationType, id: chatReference.ConversationId, tenantId: chatReference.ConversationTenantId);
var convReference = new ConversationReference(activityId: chatReference.ActivityId, user: user, bot: bot, conversation: conversationAccount, channelId: chatReference.ChannelId, serviceUrl: chatReference.ServiceUrl);
```

When running:

```
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(messageActivity);
```

I'm getting the following error from Bot Connector I think:

> Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'
>
> {"message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}

Why this is happening? Knowing that `AppId` and `AppPwd` are correct.

Comment: db entities are unrelated - leave them out. It's about your connection - post code about your account and/or can you even connect using similar protocols (like PostMan or Curl)

Answer (score 0):

There are series of steps to be followed to avoid the error occurred.

**1. Disable security and test on localhost**

Check the App ID and password in configuration file and delete those for testing

```
"MicrosoftAppId": "",
"MicrosoftAppPassword": ""
```

As you are using the core .Net framework. add or edit settings in ***appsettings.json***

**2. Check the App ID and password of bot**

Now need to check whether the App ID and password are matching or not.

These instructions and procedure include [CURL](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html) usage

To verify that your bot's app ID and password are valid, issue the following request using ***cURL***, replacing ***APP_ID*** and ***APP_PASSWORD*** with your bot's app ID and password.

```
curl -k -X POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_PASSWORD&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.botframework.com%2F.default"
```

This request attempts to exchange your bot's app ID and password for an access token. If the request is successful, you will receive a JSON payload that contains an access_token property, amongst others.

```
{"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3599,"ext_expires_in":0,"access_token":"eyJ0eXAJKV1Q..."}
```

***3. Enable security and test on localhost***

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="MicrosoftAppId" value="APP_ID" />
  <add key="MicrosoftAppPassword" value="PASSWORD" />
</appSettings>
```

if you are using bot framework SDK for .NET use the above code block

For complete reference of the procedure. [Check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-authentication-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)

Comment: What do you mean by disabling/enabling security and test on localhost?? As for point 2, tried it with postman and it returned an access token with the `AppId` and `AppPwd` used.

Comment: disabling and enabling are to check whether all the security parameters are working fine or not. It's just checking in a rapid way. It's a general error to get "Unauthorized". By checking connectivity tokens in local we can find some break though for the problem.